# Java - Trouble parsing SimpleDateFormat hours, 00 and 02 works but 01 doesn't

Tags: java, date

I'm parsing a date, "00:45:00 Mar:2017", "01:45:00 Mar:2017" and "02:45:00 Mar:2017".

All of the others give the correct output, besides "01:45:00 Mar:2017", which always rounds to "02:45:00 Mar:2017".

**Code**

```
try {
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:dd MMM:yyyy");

    Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse("01:45:26 Mar:2017");

    System.out.print(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    System.out.print(e.getMessage());
}
```

**Output from "00:45:26 Mar:2017"**

```
Sun Mar 26 00:45:00 GMT 2017
```

**Output from "01:45:26 Mar:2017"**

```
Sun Mar 26 02:45:00 BST 2017
```

**Output from "02:45:26 Mar:2017"**

```
Sun Mar 26 02:45:00 BST 2017
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Day zero?

Your pattern says the third pair of digits is day-of-month (`dd`) but there cannot be a day number zero as seen in your examples with `00`.

I suspect that third pair of digits is actually *seconds* rather than *day-of-month*, and that your day-of-month is missing.

## UK DST Cutover

Yes indeed, in the UK the Daylight Saving Time (DST) cutover “Spring forward” is 2017-03-29 at 01:00. [Described here](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/uk/london?year=2017):

> Mar 26, 2017 - Daylight Saving Time Started
>   When local standard time was about to reach
>   Sunday, March 26, 2017, 1:00:00 am clocks were turned forward 1 hour to 
>   Sunday, March 26, 2017, 2:00:00 am local daylight time instead

## Formatting patterns are case-sensitive

Another problem: You used lowercase `hh` where you probably should be using uppercase `HH` for 24-hour clock.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

Also, you are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy. Supplanted by the java.time classes.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the British clocks change on the 26th of March, at 1:00.